# How to restrict your workflow to be only run by members of your organisation [Github-actions]

Tags: github-actions

My org wants to use our CI tool on our public repos. Currently, anyone could just trigger the workflows and eat into our AWS accounts. Is there a way to set our workflows so they can only be run by our org members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to change any default settings since [only users with Write access to your repo should be able to trigger actions](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26622#discussioncomment-3252561)  and by default, the public should not have direct write access.

Unfortunately at the moment there is no way to check if your organization contains the `github.actor` that triggered the workflow.

If you have GitHub Enterprise, you can create a protected environment where [an approval is required before the workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#required-reviewers).

Technically you *could* check who is triggering the action against a list of usernames (shown below), but nothing stops someone with Write access from modifying the workflow yml to add themselves to the list of users who can trigger the workflow_dispatch action. **Therefore this is not recommended.**

```yaml
if: contains('["kingthorin","lpoulter"]', github.actor)
```

For example:

```yaml
name: Docker Build Action
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:   
  build:
    if: contains('["kingthorin","lpoulter"]', github.actor)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build .
```